# MySQL: Limitar gravação de registro baseado em valor de outra tabela

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma tabela `A` com um campo `start_date` e outro `end_date`.

Tenho uma tabela `B` com um campo `date`.

Existe algum meio de garantir que um registro só seja salvo em `B` quando `B.date` estiver entre `A.start_date` e `A.end_date`?

Eu sei fazer isso tratando a inserção via PHP. Mas quero saber se existe algo que possa ser feito no Banco que garanta esse tipo e integridade. Busco algo na linha de ação das constraints (mas qualquer solução é bem vinda!)

Comment: Pesquise como criar um TRIGGER no UPDATE

Comment: Via trigger é possível, mas acredito que você precisará usar os 3 (insert, delete e update) para garantir que **nenhuma** operação seja feita em caso de não atender essas regras. *Conselho: se essa regra for algo relacionado a controle de 'fechamento' (movimentações retroativas ou fora de competência) fuja do banco e trate na aplicação, já que você domina mais. Caso contrário você se tornará o fiel escudeiro do banco de dados para o resto da vida desse sistema*

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza concordo totalmente sobre a parte da aplicação. Acho que delegar inteligencia demais pro DB é perder o controle da situação. Aliás, se tem uma coisa que eu vejo de feio em alguns sistemas comuns aqui na região (em especial Delphi + PgSQL) é que os caras põe tanta lógica no DB, que o treco tem efeito colateral a todo momento.

Comment: @Bacco Sim, é uma prática muito comum em sistemas legados e um problema que se não cuidarmos acaba se propagando nos atuais. A tecnologia (e técnicas) que temos disponível hoje vieram para resolver problemas altamente cabeludos desse tipo de condutas que eram adotadas nos sistemas mais antigos... se não ficarmos atentos, vamos só continuar enxugando gelo com toalhinhas hi-tec -.-'

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza É uma operação simples e não retroagirá. Ao criar um evento, preciso garantir que ele esteja entre o intervalo de disponibilidade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem sim, você pode fazer um `INSERT` à partir de um `SELECT` onde em sua clausula `WHERE` estará determinada que a data tenha que estar entre o período na `tabela_a` aí basta apenas limitar a consulta a 1 para que insira apenas 1 vez o registro, mesmo encontrando mais ocorrências, por exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela_a(
    start_date DATE, 
    end_date DATE
);
CREATE TABLE tabela_b(
    campo1 varchar(255), 
    campo2 varchar(255), 
    campo3 varchar(255), 
`date` DATE
);

INSERT INTO tabela_a(
    start_date, 
    end_date) 
VALUES
    ('2018-03-01', '2018-03-30'),
    ('2018-03-01', '2018-03-29'),
    ('2018-03-01', '2018-03-05');
```

Aqui irá inserir os registros "valor1, valor2, valor3, 2018-03-27", pois encontrou na `tabela_a` ocorrências.

```
INSERT INTO tabela_b(campo1, campo2, campo3, `date`)
SELECT 
    'valor1',
    'valor2',
    'valor3',
    '2018-03-27'
FROM tabela_a
WHERE '2018-03-27' between start_date and end_date
LIMIT 1;

SELECT
    *
FROM tabela_b;
```

Segue print da consulta do que foi inserido na `tabela_b`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acho que atende sua necessidade.

Comment: Uso muito bem pensado do `INSERT .. SELECT`. +1

Comment: Usando um select para insert !? Não precisa do values ?

Comment: Uau!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @RBZ, não é necessário.

Comment: Bacana, dessa forma nunca tinha visto ! +1 (na verdade já dei o +1) rs